# PHP link written into page not being retrieved by a JAVASCRIPT function

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing on a page the following code with PHP. This code creates a A HREF link with the ID equal to $intIdType, which is the value of the PRIMARY KEY in  a database, and $count gets the amount of records per category on the database. All of this is inside a WHILE that reads each record and writes on the PAGE the results

```
          echo "<a href='#' id='$intIdType'>";//Starts creating the link
          echo "$intIdType -";
          echo $arrBusinessTypes["business_Description"]; 
          echo "(";
          echo " $count1 )"."</a>";
```

Now, after the results are on the page it will look like this:

```
$intIdType    $arrBusinessTypes       $count
--------------------------------------------
    1       -Auto Sales               ( 1 )
    2       -Auto Repair              ( 1 )
    5       -Web Desig & I.T. Services( 2 )
    6       -Computer Shop            ( 1 )
```

The above result displays each rown as a link where I can click on it, but nothing happens. Even just a simple Alert in javascript does not show up. It seems that it never reaches even the Javascript at all.

What I need now is to retrieve that PHP generated code on the page by a Javascript file, that will allow me to use the hiperlink generated by PHP into the .HTML page

It works if I write directly into the page what PHP is suppose to write. I wonder if this happens because Javascript can not read posted data from PHP into the page.

The Javascript File looks like this:

```
window.onload=post_result
function post_result() {
$("#1").click(function() { //This is the HREF ID that is written by PHP into the page
    $('#list_results').load("results.php");//This seeks to run a PHP file in a DIV
    $('.title').text('Listing Categories');//This just replaces the Title in the page
})
```

I'm just a beginner trying. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `window.onload = post_result` should be `window.onload = post_result()` calling the function

Comment: If I add the () the javascript does not run at all. I have another function that loads fine without using the ()

Comment: Are you loading jQuery in your page?

Comment: Yes I am. I am using another function that uses a HREF ID from my menu to call the PHP file that brings the DATABASE results I show above. But it is from those results that the LINK does not reach the function on the Javascript File.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo "<a id='$intIdType'>";//Starts creating the link echo "$intIdType -";  
    echo "$intIdType -";  
    echo $arrBusinessTypes["business_Description"];  
    echo "("; echo " $count1 )"."</a>";
```

just remove href attribute and try

Comment: If I remove the HREF attribute, then I don't have a LINK to click on anymore. I need the HREF posted by the PHP to click on it. The Javascript function is not reading the HREF="#". IF I replace this with a URL, the link works fine, but the Javascript I have needs to read the # ID to run my other PHP functions. My problem is that I don;t know too much PHP. I wonder if I could create a PHP that will do the same of what my AJAX function is doing.

Comment: u are overriding onclick function by assigning href attribute, hence u are not able to run any function onclick of it..also u are assigning only # inside href not the link

Comment: I am not using onclick anymore. Just click from the AJAX file to see what HREF is clicked. It works when I retrieve the info from the INDEX page that has a menu, but not from the generated PHP code embedded into a DIV ID on the INDEX PAGE. So weird this. I found something on the Internet about something called NODE.JS that seems to make Javascript run as server side and not use PHP at all, but this project needs to be done in 2 days! I odn;t have time to start trying NODE.JS

Answer (score 0):

Remark #1: quote custom data when outputs it to HTML: 
echo $arrBusinessTypes["business_Description"]; must be
echo htmlspecialchars($arrBusinessTypes["business_Description"]);

Remark #2: you don't need window.onload handler here. In this piece of code you select complex way to do simple thing. Why do not write direct onclick handler? Write function loading some data depending of parameter and do something like:

```
$htmlspecialchars = function($s){return htmlspecialchars($s);};

echo <<<HTML

<a href='#' id='$intIdType' onclick='loadInfo($intIdType)'>
  $intIdType -{$htmlspecialchars($arrBusinessTypes["business_Description"])} ( $count1 )
</a>

HTML;
```

(converted to heredoc to make HTML more clean)

Comment: Still, even though brings the same data fine, the Javascript still does not retrieve the HREF ID genereted by the PHP. This is so strange. I have read that Javascript can not read servert side PHP. I wonder if that is what is happening, even though it is being written on the page.

Comment: Are you sure this variable is available at this point? What happened then you just print it to html like echo "id=$intIdType"; ?

Comment: It prints fine, this is crazy, but I also removed the variable and just typed the number 1 or another value just to test it and it does not work either. I think my problem is that I would like to have a language that would do both SERVER side and CLIENT side to not be using both. It is a pain to make them work together.